# XML Reader issue with parsing one tag

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I have xml file like this

```
<Person>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <Title>Prof</Title>
    <Class>1</Class>
</Person>
<Person>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <Title />
    <Class>2</Class>
</Person>
```

My C# Code is like this

```
XMLReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlBlock));

    while (reader.Read())

          {
            switch (reader.NodeType)

            {
                 case XmlNodeType.Element:
                       //Do Something
                       break;
                 case XmlNodeType.Text:
                       //Do Something
                       break;
                 case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                       //Do Something
                       break;
             }
    }
```

How can I identify in my code how many tags are present of the title tag?

```
<title>Prof</title> or <title />
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `reader.IsEmptyElement()`.  See documentation for `XmlReader` here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx

Comment: isEmptyNode() isn't part of XmlReader

Comment: Right, I meant IsEmptyElement, I even linked to the API and didn't notice the dyslexia.

Answer (score 0):

using the structure of your sample code, you could check:

```
   case XmlNodeType.Element:
      if (reader.Name == "title") titleCount++;
      break;
```

And if you are talking about counting non-empty the values, then also base your count on `!reader.IsEmptyElement()`.